# A program to count number of pixels in a picture?

Tags: android, colors, pixel

Is there any way or program to count number pixels(am I even saying the right thing) of different color? Or, maybe a program to measure the general area of a color... Is there any possible activities, lines, or sets of commands that may be relevant to that? (in Android)

Comment: Hmmm... you may want to group close colors together - especially in photographs, there are rarely large swaths of an identical color, so the measurement might be off. Screenshots and other computer-generated imagery, OTOH, tends to have mostly uniform colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this information is available with the [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) class. If you're ask if there is a program that already does that try [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) it is a user oriented forum.